# How to remove space between ul and li

Tags: html, css

My html and css code

```
<ul class="tabs">  
    <li><a href="#" class="tab active">Tab one</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#" class="tab">Largeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee  Tab</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#" Class="tab">Tab three</a></li>                                                                                                                                      
</ul>
<div class="content" style="overflow-x:scroll;">
    CONTENT
</div>



ul.tabs {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul.tabs li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;        
}

ul.tabs li a {  
    display:inline-block;
    width:10%;      
    margin-bottom:0px;  
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 8px 14px 8px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 9px;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 1px solid #ffcce5;  
    background: #ffcce5;
    border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;  
    text-overflow: ellipsis;    
    white-space: nowrap;    
    overflow:hidden;    
}
.content {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #464c54;
}
```

I am trying to show a tab view,everything works fine until i add

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;    
white-space: nowrap;    
overflow:hidden;
```

here a gap is show between ul and li,i could not remove the **gap(Horizontal)** without removing

```
overflow:hidden;
```

I dont know where i went wrong.

Thanks

**EDIT:**
--[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nC7Y/)

Comment: Can you give us a JSFiddle or link to an example?

Comment: @KaiFeller I have updated with jsfiddle

Comment: Iam trying to remove horizontal gap not vertical

Comment: is this?, in css content add: margin: -5px 0px;

Comment: [Agreed - @AntonioM.Mérida](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20372816/how-to-remove-space-between-ul-and-li/20373106#20373106)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`inline-block` adds white space between elements.

Write elements on same line rather than writing them on separate line to resolve problem.

Change

```
<ul class="tabs">  
    <li><a href="#" class="tab active">Tab one</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#" class="tab">Largeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee  Tab</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#" Class="tab">Tab three</a></li>                                                                                                                                      
</ul>
```

to

```
<ul class="tabs">  
    <li><a href="#" class="tab active">Tab one</a></li><li><a href="#" class="tab">Largeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee  Tab</a></li><li><a href="#" Class="tab">Tab three</a></li>                                                                                                                                      
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.content {
    margin-top:-1px;
}
```

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/C4Hn7/5)

Comment: @hiral i am trying to remove horizontal space(that appears to be between ul and div)

Comment: @user2779544 which space?? I dont see any space plz elaborate

Comment: @Hiral the horizontal space(white) between div border(black) and the **ul.tabs li a** border(#ffcce5)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3nC7Y/1/ - Without space
http://jsfiddle.net/3nC7Y/ - With space. I hope this is what you are mentioning. @user2779544 - Right?

Comment: @hiral ok igot, can u pls say why the space appear just by adding **overflow:hidden**,because if remove this css from  **ul.tabs li a** the space disappears

Comment: @user2779544 space stays [see](http://jsfiddle.net/C4Hn7/2/) withouto `overflow:hidden`, and [see](http://jsfiddle.net/C4Hn7/1/) with `overflow:hidden`. Difference is of `ellipses` not horizontal space.

Comment: @hiral can't get u here(**Difference is of ellipses not horizontal space.**),do u mean the horizontal space appears because of ellipses

Comment: Sorry for pasting wrong links. Consider [demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/C4Hn7/5/) and [demo2] (http://jsfiddle.net/C4Hn7/6/) I dont see any difference between then 2 demos except ellipses.

Comment: stiil u miss,pls see it again in ur both links,the black border around the div

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3nC7Y/1/)**

**The CSS Change:**

```
.content {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #464c54;
    margin-top: -5px;    
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

inline-block adds white space between elements. There are many different ways to do this, but my favourite is to simply use HTML comments so that you can keep good formatting of your code.

```
<ul class="tabs">  
    <li><a href="#" class="tab active">Tab one</a></li><!--  
    --><li><a href="#" class="tab">Largeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee  Tab</a></li><!--  
    --><li><a href="#" Class="tab">Tab three</a></li>                                                                                                                                      
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use just this

```
ul {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

[Working example](https://codepen.io/Ferie/pen/zYObxRv)

Comment: Did you try this before suggesting it? Do you know what it does to the text of the `<li>` elements in the `<ul>`?

Comment: Yes I did. It does this https://codepen.io/Ferie/pen/zYObxRv exactly what the question is asking: removing the white space between the `li`

Comment: The example works because there is another font-size for the '<li>' elements. Without that the `<li>` would also get `font-size: 0;`. If someone tried to use this that didn't have a font-size set on their li elements it wouldn't work for them.

Comment: That's obvious.

Answer (score -1):

In your css apply this style. This will only remove the gap betwenn the ul and the div

```
ul.tabs li a {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: Not the case, to use inline-flex, you would have to put flex on its container. Also, this would not solve the problem below IE10. So for most people isn't really a useable solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/9F2Lk/1/